# Выбор базы данных для ASP.NET MVC веб-сайта

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Привет всем!
Нужна небольшая помощь с выбором базы данных для ASP.NET MVC сайта. Раньше при разработке веб-проектов на C# встречался только с интранет-порталами и выбор всегда был очевиден - MS SQL Server. А сейчас требуется сайт-визитка с блоговой частью и возможностью редактирования как и постов в блоге, так и обычных страниц с информацией. Заголовки, текст страниц, списки боковых меню, в общем вот такие всякие мелочи должны быть подвластны правкам. Сам сайт предполагается расположить не на внутреннем сервере компании, а где-нибудь на хостинге. Пока у меня выбор пал SQL Server Compact Local Database. Может быть что сообщество подскажет?
Спасибо!

P.S. Раньше для разработки сайтов использовал другие языки. С Microsoft'ом только недавно сдружился. Это, чтобы вы меня не пинали:)

Comment: Про «чтобы не пинали»: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818/181472

Comment: @NickVolynkin - спасибо, конечно. Но почему кто-то может спокойно ответить, а кто-то начинает вы**ываться и говорить, что не по теме, удалить, редактировать и т.д. Не можешь помочь, нечего сказать по теме? Пройди мимо.

Comment: Вопрос действительно не по теме сайта, потому что это опросник. На него невозможно дать точный ответ, только разные субъективные мнения от разных людей, которые не несут ответственности за принятое вами решение. Вопрос прошел стандартную для всех вопросов модерацию и был отмечен требующим правки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использовать нужно ту СУБД, которую вы знаете как минимум на базовом уровне; с программированием которой не возникнет критических проблем.

Иными словами, если вы раньше работали с SQL Server и знакомы со средой окружения, то нужно просто продолжить работу с ним и не заниматься выбором "модных" технологий.

Microsoft SQL Server - это имя. Это продукт, работающий в куче датацентров по всему миру и ошибочно думать, что он в чем-то не дотягивает до стандартов или уступает другим СУБД.

Отсюда: зачем набивать шишки на изучении новых технологий *в процессе разработки продуктивного решения* (сайта/приложения), когда есть знакомая СУБД, опыт работы с которой вы уже имеете?

Comment: "Отсюда: зачем набивать шишки на изучении новых технологий в процессе разработки сайта/приложения" - это мнение ошибка, все остальное пожалуй верно.

Comment: @Mirdin Почему ошибка? Хотелось бы аргументов.

Comment: Предлагаете не набивать шишки? А каким образом вы получите, тот самый, опыт работы?

Comment: Опыт работы и навыки надо приобретать в тестовых проектах, пилотах и пр. А здесь, насколько я понял, речь идет о продакшене (создании сайта на ASP.NET/MVC). Именно поэтому я добавил в ответ важное определение: не стоит набивать шишки на изучении новых технологий _в процессе разработки сайта/приложения_. А технологии изучать конечно же надо! И совершенствоваться. Но только в тестовой песочнице ))

Comment: Риски конечно оценивать надо, но не стоит так сильно боятся "шишок". Это все, естественно, ИМХО.

Comment: Спасибо за советы!

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую использовать SQLITE. Это портативная СУБД, поддерживаемая кучей инструментов от Linq2SQL и до NHibernate.

1. Простота использования (подключил и все, см. п.2).
2. Отсутствие необходимости настройки сервера СУБД .
3. Возможность простого распространения со своим продуктом (состоит из 1го .dll файла).
4. Полностью свободная лицензия.
5. Кроссплатформенность.
6. Высокая скорость (за счет того что все в одной библиотеке).
7. Очень экономичная, в плане ресурсов, архитектура.
   Поэтому для небольших проектов (Такие как простые веб-сайты, небольшие игры, и тд) считаю SQLITE лидером из существующих СУБД.